# Sendmail access_db configuration. How is it used and how to write it

Tags: configuration, sendmail

I am reading about the access_db feature of sendmail. Apparently it looks promising as a preventive way to stop spamming.

I have several questions related to how access_db is used. So basically I specify a set of rules in the access file, and sendmail will check this database to see if it should do anything about an email.

1. How about the mails that do not fit any of the specify rules? What's the default behavior?
2. Can I use regular expression? For example, will "To:*@spam.com REJECT" work?
3. If I only have "paypal.com RELAY", does it mean my sendmail will accept and send emails originated from or destined to paypal.com?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If a rule does not match the ones in access_db, then it does not affect accepting or denying the message. The message continues to get processed by the rest of the rules.
2. access_db (and whatever wildcards, but not regular expressions) is described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120926191336/http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/). If you want regular expressions you either have to write your own rule sets that mimic access_db behavior but use a regular expression map, or use a milter, like [MIMEDefang](http://www.mimedefang.org), or [milter-regex](http://www.benzedrine.cx/milter-regex.html).
3. It is best to use rules that begin with `From:` or `Connect:` instead of plain IP addresses or domains, so as not to have to think whether the rule is about the domain name of the host that connects to your host, or the domain name of the sender's address (they are not necessarily the same).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I'm trying to do is to use the access db to strictly restrict email behavior. So I want sendmail to only allow emails that's originating from localhost, and destined to *@mydomain.com only. Is it possible to do that? Because then I'll have to somehow say "if not allowed by access db, reject".

Comment: My "To:domain.com REJECT" doesn't seem to be working, I tested it by invoking sendmail on the server. I guess the problem is I had "Connect:localhost RELAY" at the first line, and thus this rule already allows my sendmail request. So I'm wondering if rules written ahead of other rules will be the dominant rule?

Comment: Did you rebuild access.db after editing /etc/mail/access ?

Comment: The easiest way to implement the policy you describe is to install MIIMEDefang and provide (in Perl) your version of filter_recipient.

Comment: Yes I rebuilt the access.db... After a few retries I found that I have to specify FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients') for the "To:" rejection to work...!!

Comment: Still, what's the right way of saying "only allow mails sent to domain xxx"? I can say "reject mails sent to xxx" but the list can go on forever...

Comment: I figured that my policy is not possible to be enforced by using access db. I'll have to either learn how to write my own rule set or learn MIMEDefang or milter-regex... Thanks @adamo for the help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

**Howto use a Regex  in Sendmail**

I was getting spammed by all numeric domains, like 3456.com, 
at first I added 10,000 entries to access.db, that was ridiculous.

In your sendmail.mc file , at the bottom, after the mailers, 
you can add a regex like this.

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
Kallnumbers regex -a@MATCH @[0-9]+\.com
LOCAL_RULESETS
SLocal_check_mail
R$+     $: $(allnumbers $1 $)
R@MATCH     $#error $: "550 Rejected."
```

You can copy most of it verbatum, just change a few things.

Define your regex and give it an identifier, prefix it with a `K`
my identifer is `allnumbers` and my regex is `[0-9]+\.com`

```
   Kallnumbers regex -a@MATCH @[0-9]+\.com
```

the last two define the match and action taken

```
R$+     $: $(allnumbers $1 $)
R@MATCH     $#error $: "550 Rejected.
```

I realize that looks very cf, but it goes in the mc.